# browser back button not loading proper content when using ng-view (angular js in front-end; node+express on backend)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, node.js

Intially when i use / i can see home.html getting sucessufully to index.html then i click `<a ng-href="#/club>` the club page is loaded successfully, but then i press back button then only header and footer of home.html is seen and in between complete blank page

Below are following files:

appRoutes.js --> for routing on angular side

clubCtrl.js --> club controller

clubService.js --> club service to fill data from node

Routes.js --> partial sample of retriving data from database and sending response

club.html --> partial club view file

home.html --> partial home page

index.html --> file on which club.html will get dynamically displayed using ng-view.

app.js -> injecting all modules

**appRoutes.js**

```
    angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider',  function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: 'MainController'
            })

            // nerds page that will use the NerdController
            .when('/club', {
                templateUrl: 'views/club.html',
                controller: 'ClubController'
            }); 

    }]);
```

**ClubCtrl.js**

```
    angular.module('ClubCtrl', []).controller('ClubController', [ '$http','Club', function($http, Club) {
        var club = this;
        club.data = {};
        Club.getClubData().then(function(response){
            club.data = response.data;
        });
    }]);
```

**ClubService.js**

```
    angular.module('ClubService', []).factory('Club', ['$http', function($http) {

        return {
            getClubData : function() {
                return $http.get('/api/club');
            }
          };
    }]);
```

**Routes.js**

```
    module.exports = function(app) {
        app.get('/', function(req, res) {
                console.log("routes send get(*)");
                res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html')); // load our public/index.html file
            });
        app.get('/api/club', function(req, res){
            console.log("routes send get /club");
        con.query("select * from club_data", function(err, rows,field) {
        if (!err)
        {
            console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
            res.json(rows);
        }
        else
            console.log('Error while performing Query. ', err);
            });
        });

    };
```

**Club.html**

```
        </div>
              <div class="row " >
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 image-feature" ng-repeat='dat in main.data'>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img ng-src="images/club/{{dat.imagename}}"alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>{{ dat.name }}</h3>
                            <p>{{dat.desccription}}</p>
                            <p>{{dat.date}}</p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">I'm Going!</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**home.html**

```
  <h1>Party</h1>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    <p>"Anytime I'm at a club or a party, I'm dancing from beginning to end."<br>--Agnes Bruckner</p>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="about-item scrollpoint sp-effect2">
                            <a href="#/club" style="text-decoration:none"></a>
```

**index.html**

```
    <body ng-app="staygala" ng-controller="MainController">

        <!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
```

**app.js**

```
        angular.module('staygala', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'MainCtrl', 'ClubCtrl', 'ClubService']);
```

On browser console:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'restart' of undefined**  i'm seeing this error while i press back. Also it looks there is no call to Get / when i press back button but when page starts there is call to same

Comment: any help here... or if need some more explanation to question i can help

Comment: even after two weeks no help, i search alot but unable to figure out :(